# Syntax error on query_vars while handling with Jquery

Tags: ajax, query, errors

I am building my own ajax load more. It works good on main query or other custom queries. But when i try it in search page query, browser console gives syntax error.

Here is query args:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    's'              => $s,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'order'          => 'DESC',
);

$searchPosts = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $searchPosts->have_posts() ) :


    while( $searchPosts->have_posts() ) :
        $searchPosts->the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'main-feed' );

    endwhile;

else :

    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

endif;

$vars = $searchPosts->query_vars;

?>

<script>
    var postsMain = '<?php echo json_encode( $vars ) ?>',
        currentPageMain = <?php echo $vars[ 'paged' ] ?>,
        maxPageMain = <?php echo $searchPosts->max_num_pages ?>
</script>

<?php
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

The error is `postsMain = '<?php echo json_encode( $vars ) ?>`

I marked faulty line. You can check here:

[image]

**UPDATE !**
The error shows only when put 's' => $s, arg to query args.

Comment: try with https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: it is not clear (to me at least) what is the problem/error

Comment: It gives a syntax error in browser. So i can't run ajax. Look at here:https://i.imgur.com/Pbj6KBY.png

Comment: @Kaperto i think wp_localize_script works only main query. But i am trying on custom query.

Comment: can it be a non-escaped single quote in `["wp_posts.post_title LIKE '{` ?